# How I display photo from google place api using geturl()?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

```
function createPhotoMarker(place) {

var photos = place.photos;

if (!photos) {

    return;
  }

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    title: place.name,
    icon: photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 35, 'maxHeight': 35})
  });

}
```

I use above function but nothing been worked...

Comment: what exactly do you pass as argument(`place`) to the function(how do you call the function)?

Comment: I want these photoes as marker..so I call this function in "function createMarkers(results, status)" such like as "for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
             createPhotoMarker(results[i]);
         }"

Comment: yes, but what's the contents of the `place` object, i.e. `results[i]`?  Show us some sample data pls

Comment: I got it..just using updated version of javascript of google api..nothing else. Thanks for comments..@Dr.Molle n @duncan